# Does disabling project in jenkins stop the wehbhoot trigger?

Tags: git, jenkins-plugins

I have a setup where git hook commit will trigger my jenkins job to fire. I want few jobs not to fire for all the commits so if disable the project, will it stop from firing even the webhook triggers the jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you disable the project in Jenkins, webhook will not be able to trigger the job